# Why isn't write-access to NTFS partitions provided with Mac OS X?

Tags: filesystems

Does Microsoft simply not allow it or is it because Apple refuses to pay licensing?

I know there are software workarounds, but my question is simply WHY?

Comment: The question is a bit misleading since the NFTS-3G driver enables read/write access to NTFS partitions.  A less misleading question would be "Why isn't write-access to NTFS partitions provided with Mac OS X?"

Answer (score 7):

It is a licensing issue. NTFS is Microsoft's proprietary format and they hold the rights to it.

A developer [asked on the MSDN forums](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/isvtoolsprocessesandarchitecture/thread/699e4f81-e54c-4326-b775-17c68526a1bd) about getting a license to the NTFS specs for an app he was writing but was unable to get that information. There is (limited) [information available](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc758691%28WS.10%29.aspx) in the Technical Reference.

The [Wikipedia page on NTFS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NTFS) mentions a couple of third-party solutions:

> Mac OS X v10.3 and later include read-only support for NTFS-formatted partitions. The GPL-licenced NTFS-3G also works on Mac OS X through FUSE and allows reading and writing to NTFS partitions. A proprietary solution for Mac OS X with read/write access is "Paragon NTFS for Mac OS X".[23]

Comment: @nagal Excellent find and it is a recent discussion.

Answer (score 2):

There's no concrete evidence that I have found online to say why / why not, however I believe you're correct in that it's a licensing issue.

Snow Leopard will see HFS+ drivers being used with Boot Camp and Windows - meaning you can use your HFS+ formatted drives in Windows.

Perhaps we'll see a similar trend from Microsoft regarding NTFS - a possibility, given that Exchange support is now coming to Snow Leopard.

Comment: ..but you'll only be able to read from your HFS+ drives from Windows, to "prevent PC viruses from affecting Mac OS X" which is.. err.. questionable http://www.apple.com/macosx/refinements/enhancements-refinements.html

Comment: As dumb as it sounds I think that will actually be okay for the vast majority of users - I know that personally, all I've wanted was to copy my iTunes library across when I'm using BootCamp.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think it's necessarily a licensing issue.  The Linux kernel is able to read NTFS filesystems, as well as write (but they consider that "dangerous."  Mac OS X has the ability to read NTFS, but not write.

Answer (score 1):

From the [NTFS Wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NTFS):

> Details on the implementation's
>   internals are not released, which
>   makes it difficult for third-party
>   vendors to provide tools to handle
>   NTFS.

This suggests that it's some sort of licensing issue.  Were it not for the [NTFS-3G project](http://www.ntfs-3g.org), there would probably be no way for most non-Windows operating systems (Linux, Mac OS X, etc.) to write to NTFS partitions.

Comment: Fun fact. I had NTFS access from Linux in 2004 and it wasn't by NTFS-3G. It could read anything but only overwrite blocks not change any metadata. I used it for lilo.